# Background image center on x y

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if their is an easy way to center my background on x and y ?

My example is simple i have a big image and i use it as a background-image. But the most important thing of my image isn't in the middle of it (red X on my image) .

So when i resize my screen my background image is centered but not the way i would like (we don't see the entire face for example). Is there a way to "change the center" by setting some x and y center position on the css ?

html:

```
<div id="service_4">
</div>
```

css:

```
#service_4 { 
    background-image: url(../img/service/service_4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

[image]

Thx guys

EDIT : Change the image to make it more clear

Comment: Important item? Really? Could you please provide a [mcve] that has HTML and CSS?

Comment: What is this important thing? Is it text? Is it an element? is it part of the jpeg itself?

Comment: In my example, the women and the syringe

Comment: So it's just a part of the image itself that's always centered?

Comment: The problem is that with "background-position: center" when my screen is smaller my background is centered to the center of the image. I would like it to be centered on a particular point to always see the women and the syringe.

Comment: Ah ha, that's what I thought you meant.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need

`background-size: contain` or `background-size: cover`

Answer (score 0):

use an inline-block helper with height: 100% and vertical-align: middle for both elements(best cross-browser compatability).

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        with:400px;
        height:400px;
        border:1px solid #cccccc;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .img-center{
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin:auto;
    }
    .helper {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
      vertical-align: middle;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="box">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img src="http://www.wowescape.com/images/uploads/images/8758405601.jpg" class="img-center" alt="alt"/>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Click [CodepenSnippet](https://codepen.io/gvreddys99/pen/JNNREY) to see the output

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it should center the image at any screen size. And the text would not have impact on the background image size

```
@media and screen (max-width:640){
#service_4 { 
   background-position: right center:
}}
```

Comment: The text isn't my problem here. The problem is how it is centered. I would like my image to be centered on a particular point when my screen begin smaller and not to be centered on the center as "backgroud-position: center" does

Comment: You can use media query for that. Updated my code. You have to change the max-width size to the size in which you want the background to change position

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case I would define the background-position as:

```
background-position: top right;
```

since that obviously is the part which is most important for you (i.e. the face)

Comment: Yes but if the size of the screen was even smaller i would only see the right part of the head. I would like it to be centered but on a particular point of my image.